# Prove that $102×102$ board cannot be covered without overlapping by $1×4$ polyminoes .

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that $102×102$ board cannot be covered without overlapping by $1×4$ polyminoes .
The bove question is taken from Mathematical Circles by Dimitri Fomin, Sergey Genkin and IIa Itenberg.

The solution given in the book is as follows:

> Apply an analogous coloring using $4$ colors. Since each polymino covers either $4$ boxes of the same color or four boxes of different colors , we can conclude that the difference between the numbers of the boxes of color $A$ and of color $B$ is divisible by $4$:(regardless of which color $A$ and $B$ we choose). An easy calculation shows that there are $2652$ boxes of 1st color ,$ 2652$ boxes 2nd color , $2550$ boxes of 3rd color and $2550$ boxes of the 4th color . The difference between the number of the boxes of the 1st and 3rd color is $102$ which is not divisible by $4$. This completes the proof.

However,  I am not getting the idea behind the proof. What does they mean by saying "we can conclude that the difference between the numbers of the boxes of color $A$ and of color $B$ is divisible by $4$" ? How does they conclude this? I am not getting it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that the coloring mentioned in the solution is something like: each block in a row is colored with a same color, and $n$-th row and $m$-th row has a same color if and only if $m\equiv n \,(\mathrm{mod}\,4)$. Now assume that you are putting polyminoes one by one, and count the colors covered at each step. If a polymino is set vertically ($4\times 1$), then it covers four different colors, so number of covered tiles for each color will increase by one, which means that the difference of the numbers will remain the same. If the polymino is set horizontally ($1 \times 4$), then it will cover 4 tiles with same colors, and corresponding color's number of covered tiles will increase by 4. In this case, the difference of the numbers **mod 4** will remain the same. So if you can tile all the tiles perfectly, then the differences of number of tiles for each color should be divisible by 4, which is impossible for $102 \times 102$ board.

---

[image]

If there's no polymino on the board, then the number of covered tiles for each color is all zero. Now, if you put **1**, then all the numbers increases by 1, and becomes $(1, 1, 1, 1)$. Next, if you put **2**, then only green color's number increases by 4, so the numbers become $(1, 1, 5, 1)$. No matter how much polyminoes you put on the board, the differences of the numbers of covered tiles will always be divisible by 4.

Comment: @Sewoo Lee... But can u please explain what do u mean by "If a polymino is set vertically (1×4), then it covers four different colors, so number of covered tiles for each color will increase by one, which means that the difference of the numbers will remain the same. " and " the difference of the numbers mod 4 will remain the same."?..i mean which numbers are u talking about?....

Comment: @Franklin I added some picture and explanations - hope this helps you!

Comment: ...Thanks a lot! But I am not getting what do u mean by "difference of the numbers $mod 4$" ? What are the numbers u r talking about whose remainders remains same ? Are u talking about number of boxes of each coloring covered until now?And their differences taken two at a time?

Comment: @Franklin Exactly. For example, if you put the first polymino, the differences are all zero. After you put the second polymino, differences are 0 or 4. No matter how much polyminoes you put, the 6 differences of 4 numbers (number of boxes of each coloring covered until now), are all divisible by 4.

Comment: ...Thanks ! But how do u conclude that if we can tile it the differences of number of tiles for each color should be divisible by 4?and why is it not possible? I am not getting this part?...

Comment: I think you almost got it. For each step, the differences number of boxes of each coloring covered until the step should be divisible by 4. Now, if you can cover the board perfectly, after $102 \times 102 / 4$ steps, you will eventually cover all the boxes, and the differences should be divisible by 4 as before. However, they aren't if you count the number of colors on the board - there are 2652 reds, 2652 blues, 2550 greens, and 2550 yellows. The difference $2562 - 2550 = 102$ is not divisible by 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So this means that we were first tiling it ...if we tile it in the first step in whichever way u have shown in the figure ..the differences will be divisible by $4$ and if we continue tiling it the remainder will not change for each difference i.e it will still be divisible by $4$ ..However , if we could tile it possibly then again the differences will still be divisible by $4$ but it is not true as in the calculation u shown above! This was the idea , right?

Comment: @Franklin You're right!

Comment: ...Thanks a lot!....

Comment: +1 (also) : high quality visual presentation + going the extra mile in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Color each $(m,n)$ square red if and only if $m\equiv n\bmod 4$, giving several diagonals of red squares. A $1×4$ polyonimo will then cover one red square and we would need $(102×102)/4=2601$ of these polyomimoes to cover the board. Thus with a successful tiling we would have exactly $2601$ red squares. But the actual total number of red squares is

$2+6+10+...+98+102+98+94+...+6+2=2602,$

and we are contradicted. We would need a $2×2$ polyonimo somewhere to cover two of the red squares.